# Standardized residuals check in a ARMA-GARCH model

Tags: time-series, arima, autocorrelation, garch, diagnostic

If standardized residuals of an ARMA-GARCH model show some autocorrelation, while the squared standardized residuals look white noise, what can we infer about the specification of the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **conditional mean** model (ARMA) is likely inadequate. If it were adequate, there would not be remaining autocorrelation in the standardized residuals. You may wish to try alternative specifications, e.g. change the lag orders of ARMA.
The **conditional variance** model (GARCH) is likely adequate, as the squared standardized residuals look like white noise.